# Creating multiple panels within a multi-page longtable

Tags: tables, longtable

I am able to create multiple Panels in a normal table using tabular environment. I also need a description for each panel. The footnotes for the last panel work as footnote for the entire table. Below is a MWE using `table` package. I want to find the same using `longtable` package. The tables in MWE are much smaller than my real project. Ideally I need one panel per page.

I am also not able to justify Panel A (below) to centre.

Edit (23/05/21): The example here shows how to make multiple panels in longtable. Need to use `xltabular` package. Link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mysjtbnfmypz

The MWE below is available at overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/kxmrshgmgcpb

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,right=0.5in,left=0.5in]{geometry}


\begin{document}


\newgeometry{margin=0.5in}
\begin{landscape}

\begin{table}

\caption[Robustness Results]{\textbf{Robustness Regressions: Different measures of disagreement and turnover, and five-year subperiods}}\label{tab:mytab}

\begin{threeparttable}
\phantom{ }\\
\textbf{Panel A: Different Measures of Disagreement}\\
Describe Panel A


\centering\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{6.4cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{3.2cm}>{}p{3.2cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{4}{c}{$L\_TURN_t$} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-5}
$FDISP_{t-1}$ & $\phantom{-}0.017$* & $\phantom{-}0.018$* & $\phantom{-}0.017$* & $\phantom{-}0.015$\\
 & \phantom{-}($0.009$) & \phantom{-}($0.009$) & \phantom{-}($0.009$) & \phantom{-}($0.009$)\\
\midrule
$\% \: R^2 \: \textrm{Explained}$ & $\phantom{-}3.940$ & $\phantom{-}3.530$ & $\phantom{-}4.290$ & $\phantom{-}7.580$\\
$\textrm{Observations}$ & \phantom{-}111,298 & \phantom{-}111,298 & \phantom{-}111,298 & \phantom{-}111,298\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}



\begin{tablenotes}
\item Panel A notes\\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\pagebreak

\begin{threeparttable}
\phantom{ }\\
\textbf{Panel B: Different Measures of Turnover}\\
Describe Panel B


\centering\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2.5cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L\_TURN_t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$\Delta L\_TURN_t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L\_TURN\_GRT_t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L\_TURN\_D_t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$L\_TURN\_ILLIQ_t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$VW\_L\_TURN_t$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$EW\_L\_TURN_t$} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-2} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){3-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-4} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){5-5} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){6-6} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){7-7} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-8}
$FDISP_{t-1}$ & $\phantom{-}0.019$*** & $-0.004$*** & $\phantom{-}0.030$*** & $-0.010$** & $\phantom{-}0.008$** & $-0.014$*** & $-0.013$***\\
 & \phantom{-}($0.007$) & \phantom{-}($0.001$) & \phantom{-}($0.007$) & \phantom{-}($0.004$) & \phantom{-}($0.003$) & \phantom{-}($0.004$) & \phantom{-}($0.004$)\\
\midrule
$\% \: R^2 \: \textrm{Explained}$ & $\phantom{-}5.030$ & $\phantom{-}0.000$ & $\phantom{-}1.710$ & $\phantom{-}0.550$ & $\phantom{-}0.070$ & $\phantom{-}0.630$ & $\phantom{-}0.680$\\
$\textrm{Observations}$ & \phantom{-}657,714 & \phantom{-}657,714 & \phantom{-}657,714 & \phantom{-}657,714 & \phantom{-}657,714 & \phantom{-}657,714 & \phantom{-}657,714\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}



\begin{tablenotes}
\item Panel B notes\\
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\pagebreak

\begin{threeparttable}
\phantom{ }\\
\textbf{Panel C: Five-year subperiods}\\
Describe Panel C


\centering\fontsize{8}{10}\selectfont

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4.1cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{ } & \multicolumn{9}{c}{$L\_TURN_t$} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-10}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{ }} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{1976-1979}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{1980-1984}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{1985-1989}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{1990-1994}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{1995-1999}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{2000-2004}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{2005-2009}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{2010-2014}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\em{2015-2019}} \\
\cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){2-2} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){3-3} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){4-4} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){5-5} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){6-6} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){7-7} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){8-8} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){9-9} \cmidrule(l{3pt}r{3pt}){10-10}
$FDISP_{t-1}$ & $\phantom{-}0.030$ & $\phantom{-}0.011$ & $\phantom{-}0.022$ & $\phantom{-}0.018$ & $\phantom{-}0.007$ & $\phantom{-}0.011$ & $\phantom{-}0.048$*** & $-0.008$ & $\phantom{-}0.004$\\
 & \phantom{-}($0.140$) & \phantom{-}($0.017$) & \phantom{-}($0.015$) & \phantom{-}($0.016$) & \phantom{-}($0.015$) & \phantom{-}($0.015$) & \phantom{-}($0.013$) & \phantom{-}($0.014$) & \phantom{-}($0.017$)\\
\midrule
$\% \: R^2 \: \textrm{Explained}$ & $\phantom{-}1.560$ & $\phantom{-}1.640$ & $\phantom{-}1.320$ & $\phantom{-}3.400$ & $\phantom{-}5.030$ & $\phantom{-}3.170$ & $\phantom{-}2.520$ & $\phantom{-}1.800$ & $\phantom{-}1.340$\\
$\textrm{Observations}$ & \phantom{-}7,739 & \phantom{-}16,837 & \phantom{-}46,959 & \phantom{-}74,342 & \phantom{-}95,145 & \phantom{-}106,543 & \phantom{-}111,811 & \phantom{-}111,133 & \phantom{-}91,082\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}



\begin{tablenotes}
\item In Panel A, log turnover is regressed on set of controls and several measures of disagreement. In Panel B, several measures of turnover are regressed on a set of explanatory variables and the disagreement measure $STD\_DEV$. In Panel C, log turnover regressed on set of controls and disagreement over nine 5-year subperiods. All independent variables are one month lagged variables. Definitions of all the variables appears in Appendix \ref{appendix-a2-variable-definitions}. All regression specifications have industry and year fixed effects. Within $R^2$ is the $R^2$ for within groups variation with fixed effects projected out while Adj. $R^2$ is for the entire model. \% $R^2$ explained is the percent of unexplained variation explained by including disagreement in the regression. Standard errors are double clustered by firm and year-month. Statistical significance of 10\%, 5\% and 1\% are indicated by *, ** and *** respectively.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear, what you like to obtain, so the following MWE is based on guessing.

After clean-up your code, the possible MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\mc{O{1}m}{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \begin{landscape}
\sisetup{input-open-uncertainty= ,  % <-- new
         input-close-uncertainty= , % <-- new
         table-space-text-pre=(,    % <-- new
         table-space-text-post=),   % <-- new
         table-align-text-pre=false,% <-- new
         table-format=3.3}

    \begin{table}[ht]
\caption[Robustness Results]{Robustness Regressions: Different measures of disagreement and turnover, and five-year subperiods}
\label{tab:mytab}

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption*{Panel A: Different Measures of Disagreement}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\linewidth}{X *{4}{S}}
\multicolumn{5}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}{Describe Panel B. \lipsum[66]}\\
    \toprule
    &   \mc[4]{$L\_TURN_t$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
$FDISP_{t-1}$ 
    &  0.017\tnote{*}   &  0.018\tnote{*}   &  0.017\tnote{*}   &  0.015    \\
    & (0.009)           & (0.009)           & (0.009)           & (0.009)   \\
    \midrule
\% $R^2$ Explained      
    & 3.940             & 3.530             & 4.290             & 7.580     \\
Observations
    & {111,298}         & {111,298}         & {111,298}         & {111,298} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\note{Panel A notes}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\clearpage
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption*{Panel B: Different Measures of Turnover}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X *{7}{S}}
\multicolumn{8}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}{Describe Panel C. \lipsum[66]}\\
    \toprule
    & \mc[7]{$L\_TURN_t$} \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \mc{$L\_TURN_t$}      & \mc{$\Delta L\_TURN_t$} & \mc{$L\_TURN\_GRT_t$} 
    & \mc{$L\_TURN\_D_t$}   & \mc{$L\_TURN\_ILLIQ_t$} & \mc{$VW\_L\_TURN_t$}  
    & \mc{$EW\_L\_TURN_t$} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-8}
$FDISP_{t-1}$ 
    & 0.019\tnote{***}  & -0.004\tnote{***} & 0.030\tnote{***} & -0.010\tnote{**}
    & 0.008\tnote{**}   & -0.014\tnote{***} & -0.013\tnote{***}  \\
    & (0.007)           & (0.001)           & (0.007)           & (0.004)
    & (0.003)           & (0.004)           & (0.004)           \\
    \midrule
\% $R^2$ Explained
    & 5.030     & 0.000     & 1.710     & 0.550 & 0.070 & 0.630 & 0.680 \\
Observations
    & {657,714} & {657,714} & {657,714} & {657,714} & {657,714} & {657,714} & {657,714}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize
\note{Panel B notes}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\clearpage
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption*{Panel C: Five-year subperiods}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{X *{9}{S[table-format=1.3]} }
\multicolumn{10}{p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}}{Describe Panel C}\\
\toprule
    & \mc[9]{$L\_TURN_t$} \\
    \cmidrule{2-10}
    & \mc{\em{1976-1979}} & \mc{\em{1980-1984}} & \mc{\em{1985-1989}}
    & \mc{\em{1990-1994}} & \mc{\em{1995-1999}} & \mc{\em{2000-2004}}
    & \mc{\em{2005-2009}} & \mc{\em{2010-2014}} & \mc{\em{2015-2019}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-8} \cmidrule(lr){9-9} \cmidrule(lr){10-10}
$FDISP_{t-1}$
    &  0.030  &  0.011   &  0.022   &  0.018   &  0.007 &  0.011
    &  0.048\tnote{***}  & -0.008   &  0.004 \\
    & (0.140) & (0.017)  & (0.015)  & (0.016) & (0.015) & (0.015)
    & (0.013) & (0.014)     & (0.017)\\
\midrule
\% $R^2$ Explained
    & 1.560     & 1.640     & 1.320     & 3.400     & 5.030
    & 3.170     & 2.520     & 1.800     & 1.340 \\
Observations
    & {7,739}   & {16,837}  & {46,959}  & {74,342}  & {95,145}
    & {106,543} & {111,811} & {111,133} & {91,082}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\begin{tablenotes}[para, flushleft]\footnotesize
\note{In Panel A, log turnover is regressed on set of controls and several measures of disagreement. In Panel B, several measures of turnover are regressed on a set of explanatory variables and the disagreement measure $STD\_DEV$. In Panel C, log turnover regressed on set of controls and disagreement over nine 5-year subperiods. All independent variables are one month lagged variables. Definitions of all the variables appears in Appendix \ref{appendix-a2-variable-definitions}. All regression specifications have industry and year fixed effects. Within $R^2$ is the $R^2$ for within groups variation with fixed effects projected out while Adj. $R^2$ is for the entire model. \% $R^2$ explained is the percent of unexplained variation explained by including disagreement in the regression. Standard errors are double clustered by firm and year-month.

Statistical significance of 10\%, 5\% and 1\% are indicated by *, ** and *** respectively.}
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Image of the last page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is close to what I want although I do not understand how you did it. Could you please explain it? Not all panels would be page long so I would sometimes need 2 panels in one page also.

Comment: the reason my original latex code was unclear because it originated from R package: kableExtra which takes a numeric table as input and applies latex styling to it.

Comment: @NikhilVidhani, if you like to have more table on one page, remove `\clearpage` after `table` to which you like to follow the next table. Code for tables should be self-explainatory :-), main difference to yours is: for columns in table (except the first) use `S` column type defined in `siunitx` package, which enables aligning numbers at decimal points and write symbols before numbers in math mode. If cell in this columns are not numbers, or you like to have only centered it in cells, the you must enclose it by curly brackets. `tabularx` tables require at least one column of  `X` type.

Comment: Zarko, Thanks for the explanations.

Comment: Zarko, I found a way to put multiple panels in longtable using `xltabular` package. See my example here: https://www.overleaf.com/read/mysjtbnfmypz

Comment: @NikhilVidhani, it is nice to hear that you solve your problem yourself.